# What are all the SO Careers ads?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Could somebody post all the screenshots here? (This is just for curiosity)

These are the ones I already copied

[image]
[image]

It seems each one has a different background and I wanted to know what they all looked like.

Edit: These were added by [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey). I wonder if there is one in the middle?

[image]
[image]

Edit: I posted these here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery/76748#76748

I would suggest you downvote any that have nothing but broken images. Also I would suggest stopping at -1 or -2. Actually it would be better if they were deleted but oh well.

Comment: Am I breaking a rule here or is the down vote just one person's opinion?

Comment: A downvote is always just one person's opinion.

Comment: I've never seen it all the way down to FML. Presumably the guy would be using an abacus.

Comment: I have seen it all the way down. I think it was a typewriter and a pile of papers. But I don't remember it well

Comment: I was curious a while ago and I just hit Reload enough times to see them all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [The Ad Gallery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery) (user-curated, may or may not be up-to-date)

Comment: Is it just me or are most of those broken images?

Comment: All the images in the answers are missing

Comment: Obviously the community has been slacking...

Comment: I went in and downvoted a lot of the ones that did not have any good images. Since this is Community Wiki it might be good to do that until they are negative @ChrisF @JRandom

Comment: Wow! I even got a Suffrage badge for it :) @ChrisF @JRandom

Comment: Here is my addition: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery/76748#76748